# How do I know if a game is compatible with the Wii U pro controller?

Tags: wii-u

I'm trying to decide whether I'll want a Wii U pro Controller, but I'm not finding any information on which games are going to be able to use it, and if any games are requiring it. I was thinking the back if the box might give that information, but I haven't seen that icon on the back of any boxes, but finding the back of boxes has also proven difficult.

How can I figure out if a game is compatible with the Wii U pro controller?

Comment: Given that it has all the same buttons as the casual gamepad (you walked into that one N) and Wii U games are (I think) supposed to be playable with or without the gamepad screen, shouldn't the pro controller be compatible with all games?

Comment: I doubt a game like ZombiU is playable without the 2nd screen

Comment: @JohnoBoy Yeah, most of the games won't really be playable without the screen, but that's just for the first player. What about player 2? Like the Mario game supports 4? players, can players 2-4 use wiimotes or controllers interchangably?

Comment: I'd say yes, they can.

Comment: I can tell you for a fact that the mario game does not support the Pro controller, i bought one and tried to play the mario game with it while my cousin used the wiiu game pad. the pro controller would react and sync as if it was working, but then nothing... at first we thought it was because it was out of juice, but even after charging it still nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back of the game boxes have icons indicating which input methods are supported.[image]

I was somewhat surprised that Arkham City does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the back of the game's case.

Comment: If it's anything like Wii games this should be correct

Comment: I looked at several and couldn't find any of the pro controller logos, so maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

If the game is compatible with the Wii U Pro controller, it will say on the box, and in the Instruction manual.

At least it's like that in ZombiU (you can use the Pro controller for Multiplayer), and I know my other games can't use it already.